# Declaring Entity to another Entity, get category name to be set on product category

Tags: php, symfony4

I got confused.

I am have an `ProductRepository.php` that manages all the product, then I have a `category` attribute which should connected to `CategoryRepository.php` or Category Entity.

here is my code in `ProductRepository.php`

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\Category;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Product::class);
    }

    public function transform(Product $product)
    {
        $category = Category($product->getCategory()); // error
        $category = $category->getName();

        return [
                'id'    => (int) $product->getId(),
                'name' => (string) $product->getName(),
                'category' => (int) $product->getCategory(),
                'category_name' => (string) $category,
                'SKU' => (string) $product->getSKU(),
                'price' => (float) $product->getPrice(),
                'quantity'    => (int) $product->getQuantity()
        ];
    }
```

My issue, I got an error on declaring the Category class, any idea about this?
my goal is to get the `category name` from the product's category attribute which is the `id` of the `category model`

category Model is:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CategoryRepository")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot `new` keyword before `Category()`.

Comment: And I bet the following line is `setName(...)`, not `getName(...)`

Comment: hi Jules, I wanted to find a category and not to set a new category

Comment: Alright, simply delete the line with the error. Can you edit with the content of `getName()` please ?

Comment: hmmm.. that line is to get the `category name` from the `product category` attribute which is the `id` to the `category model`

Comment: The one before, `$category = Category();`

Comment: what will be the replacement?

Comment: You need to put either an existing Category or a new one in `$category`. But can you please show the `Category` class or at least the definition of `Category::getName()`, otherwise it is hard to understand what you're doing.

Comment: here's the category model and I updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.

Assuming Product::category is a relation between Product and Category classes:

```
 $categoryName = $product->getCategory()->getName();
```

You simply get the object Category and then get its name.

Comment: thanks, I got the source at https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html